# javascript method chaining, add methods from an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

Hi I wondered whether you could help me build a method chain dynamically, I suspect this is easily done if you know how...

Using mongoose and node.js I'm querying a mongo database.
I use a function that I pass an object to which looks like this:

```
transaction = {
       model: a mongoose model
       req: Express.js request object
       res: Express.js response object
       query: a mongo db query eg, {_id:xxxxx}
       populate: [ {
         field: 'name_of_doc_field'
         select: 'field1,field2'
       } ]
    }
```

I'm constructing the query dynamically, and in the function I don't know how many fields I'll need to populate, or whether an offset or limit is required.

I want to chain my find:

```
transaction.model.find(transaction.query).skip(offset).limit(limit).exec(function(err, collection_obj){...})
```

How do i build this chain dynamically, I'll need to test whether an offset was supplied in the test object, if it was add .skip method to the chain, etc, and with the populate method, there will be an array of items, each item in that array will need a new populate method adding to the chain.

Finally, I'll need to an exec method to the end of the chain.

Thanks for your help in advance

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.4.0
    module.exports = {
      findMany: function(transaction) {
        var collection_obj, limit, offset;
        offset = parseInt(transaction.req.query.offset) || 0;
        limit = parseInt(transaction.req.query.limit) || 100;
        collection_obj = null;
        return transaction.model.find(transaction.query).skip(offset).limit(limit).exec(function(err, collection_obj) {
          return found(err, collection_obj, transaction.req, transaction.res);
        });
      },
    }
```

Comment: Your API seems quite fuzzy to me.  You say that `transaction.model` is a mongoose model.  Does that already have the `find` function you're looking for?  If not, do you expect to expand the mongoose API?

Comment: Do you want the `skip`, `limit` and `exec` methods to act on the `transaction` or on the `model`?

Comment: The reason I've separated this function, is that I'll be repeating this function on many models.
I want to find records in the given model, which is supplied by the transaction object. Am I mis-understanding something? It works as it currently stands, but doesn't handle missing properties such as a missing 'limit' and doesn't run the .populate method, because I couldn't work out how to add to the change dynamically for every element in the array.

Comment: yes, sorry, the mongoose model already has the find function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break the chain up into steps that you can conditionally perform based on the contents of `transaction`:

```
var q = transaction.model.find(transaction.query);
if (offset) {
  q = q.skip(offset);
}
if (limit) {
  q = q.limit(limit);
}
if (transaction.populate) {
  transaction.populate.forEach(function(pop) {
     q = q.populate(pop.field, pop.select);
  });
}
q.exec(function(err, collection_obj){...});
```

Comment: This does seem to work, you can probably tell I'm new to javascript.
From my understanding chaining works because the next method inherits the object output from the previous method. So here, we just set the object, 'q' and keep adding new methods to it. the exec method must inspect all the other methods attached to q. Thanks for your help.